# How to make RelativeLayout scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying make custom view in a my android application.
This is a part of my layout:

```
<com.kennyc.view.MultiStateView
    android:id="@+id/multiStateView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:msv_errorView="@layout/view_error"
    app:msv_loadingView="@layout/view_loading"
    app:msv_viewState="loading">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.intech.mishiko.views.stats.WeekHistogramView
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mean"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <com.intech.mishiko.views.stats.MeanActivityView
            android:id="@+id/mean"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin_half" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.kennyc.view.MultiStateView>
```

WeekHistogramView extends View class:

```
public class WeekHistogramView extends BaseHistogramView {
    //my code

    @Override
    onDraw() {
        //custom drawing
    }
}
```

MeanActivityView is a LinearLayout:

```
public class MeanActivityView extends LinearLayout {
    //my code
    //set and show some text fields.
}
```

All worked fine.

[image: ui works correct]

But new requariment says that i need scrollable bahaviour. 
I add ScrollView in a my code:

```
<com.kennyc.view.MultiStateView
    android:id="@+id/multiStateView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:msv_errorView="@layout/view_error"
    app:msv_loadingView="@layout/view_loading"
    app:msv_viewState="loading">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.intech.mishiko.views.stats.WeekHistogramView
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/mean"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <com.intech.mishiko.views.stats.MeanActivityView
                android:id="@+id/mean"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin_half" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</com.kennyc.view.MultiStateView>
```

But after that WeekHistogramView return 0 height. It's invisible.

I tried wrap MultiStateView in a ScrollView but nothing changed.

After that I changed RelativeLayout -> vertical LinearLayout and that doesn't work too.

[image: ui works incorrect]

Is anyone can help me?

Comment: What do you need to scroll: entire view Histogram + MeanView or just MeanView?

Comment: I'm trying scroll HistogramView and MeanView together.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `RelativeLayout` in a `LinearLayout` so that the only child of the `ScrollView` is `LinearLayout`. This will do the trick.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

          //....

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried your trick but same result. My WeekHistogramView don't show.

Comment: I have experienced bugs with trying to scroll RelativeLayouts. As I can see, the relative layout in your case could be replaced by a LinearLayout. Try to do that :)

Comment: I know what may be the problem: you have to reverse your aligments. Meaning the chart has to be align parent top and you have to place mean below chart. 
Add in chart:
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and delete android:layout_above="@+id/mean"

And in mean add android:layout_below="@+id/chart" and remove/delete android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Scroll is top to bottom and you have your views bottom to top so it will show the dominant view, the aligned bottom, and partially  show the 'above' view.

Let me know if this works for you.